# asp.net mvc application does URL redirection to facebook feed / share dialog. How to know whether the user posted or cancelled the post?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

My Asp.net MVC application uses facebook login with OWIN authentication. At one stage, it does URL redirection to **facebook share dialog** to share a link. Is there anyway to know if the user actually posted to his facebook wall / cancelled it.

Facebook mentioned that it does return **error_message** as response data when the user cancelled. (Only available if the user is logged into your app using Facebook Login). However this is not the case and we are not getting any error_message / error_code in response. Is it because that facebook doesn't recognize the facebook login (using OWIN)?

Example of the feed dialog link (as shown in the facebook documentation)
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=145634995501895&href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fexplorer

when I hit cancel, it does redirect to this below URL with error_message as response data
[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?error_code=4201&error_message=User%20canceled%20the%20Dialog%20flow#*=*](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?error_code=4201&error_message=User%20canceled%20the%20Dialog%20flow#_=_)

Is there anyway to achieve the same with asp.net mvc application that uses facebook login with OWIN authentication.

Thanks,

Comment: What would you need this info for?

Comment: We would like to show different content / url when the user cancels the feed and also to update some statistics of our site in our database..

Comment: You are not allowed to show users anything different based on whether they share your stuff or not.